# Export DBF from shapefile with ModelBuilder (to make a XY event layer)

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, export, dbf, xy

I'm using **ModelBuilder** and I need to export a shapefile to a **DBF**. Usually I go to "table option" and I click to "Export", how can I do it with ModelBuilder?

I need to do this process because I have to use the **XY Event Layer** which requires a DBF to work correctly (if you put a shapefile, the function duplicate the geometric attributes).

Comment: Try [Table To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm)

Comment: Thanks, now it should work!

Comment: A shapefile already has a `.dbf`, which can be referenced for read-only use or copied for read-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using tool [TableToTable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm) in ModelBuilder